# Unable to connect through VNC

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to configure VNC server on my Ubuntu 19.04 desktop so that I can connect to it through my windows laptop over home wifi. I followed steps mentioned https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-and-configure-tigervnc-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/

My firewall is inactive and I am unable to connect from my laptop.
I tried to connect from local vnc viewer using 127.0.0.1:5902 and it connects.

But if I give local-lan-ip:5902 I see the error "unable to connect to socket:connection refused"

I'm really not a pro at configuring stuff on linux, can someone help me figure out the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution here. VNC was bound to local host and I had to bind it to lan interface 
I ran `vncserver -localhost no` and it worked.

https://superuser.com/questions/564658/vnc-viewer-error-unable-connect-to-socket-connection-refused-111

Comment: I have used vncserver for years and years but never had trouble connecting until this morning after a change of IP address. And by gum for whatever reason, this was the fix!

Comment: Didn't work for me.